# Download current website tab as PDF within a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and one thing it needs to do is save the current page as a PDF (among other tasks).

How can I do this with a Chrome Extension?

Something like `chrome.pageCapture.saveAsPDF()` would be ideal. I found [`chrome.pageCapture.saveAsHTML()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageCapture/#method-saveAsMHTML). But `saveAsPDF` doesn't actually exist AFAICT.

Any other solutions?

Using: Mac, Chrome, Chrome extension.